# Arduino Uno to Micro SPI pinout remapping?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, microcontroller, bluetooth-lowenergy

- Web developer going into hardware so please, be gentle.

Problem: I'm currently trying to use the BlueFruit LE breakout board and an Arduino Micro, however the pinouts are different as the Micro has dedicated SPI pins whereas the UNO has SCK, MISO and MOSI doing double duty on pins 13, 12 and 11.

Question: Where in the Arduino IDE or the sample code I'm using can I change the requested pinouts?

Code:

echoDemo example sketch from Adafruit (truncated for brevity):

```
 #include <SPI.h>
 #include "Adafruit_BLE_UART.h"

 // Connect CLK/MISO/MOSI to hardware SPI
 // e.g. On UNO & compatible: CLK = 13, MISO = 12, MOSI = 11
 #define ADAFRUITBLE_REQ 10
 #define ADAFRUITBLE_RDY 2     // This should be an interrupt pin, on Uno thats #2 or #3
 #define ADAFRUITBLE_RST 9
```

As above states, the 'UNO & compatible...' are looking for the correct pins on said board.

I've done a search for the pins by name (CLK, etc) in the two #include files but haven't found their reference.

The result should be the following output in the Arduino IDE Console:

```
 Adafruit Bluefruit Low Energy nRF8001 Print echo demo
 * Advertising started
```

The second line should be returned from the BlueFruit LE board to the Micro and output to console.

My result is only the first line is output.

Understandably there are diagrams on the Arduino site where they detail the SPI pins and they're labelled clearly on the Micro (image attached). What I'm looking for is how/where to remap these pins to the Micro's pinout.

Any help, references or files to dig into would be a massive help.

[image: Arduino Micro to BlueFruit LE Needs Remap]

•• Update

Thanks to the answers below, we're one step closer.

The following changes were made to the pinout in the sketch:

```
 #include <SPI.h>
 #include "Adafruit_BLE_UART.h"

 // Connect CLK/MISO/MOSI to hardware SPI
 // e.g. On UNO & compatible: CLK = 13, MISO = 12, MOSI = 11
 #define ADAFRUITBLE_REQ SS
 #define ADAFRUITBLE_RDY 2     // This should be an interrupt pin, on Uno thats #2 or #3
 #define ADAFRUITBLE_RST 3
```

And the following is the modified ble_system.h:

```
 #ifndef BLE_SYSTEM_H_
 #define BLE_SYSTEM_H

 /*
 #define HAL_IO_RADIO_CSN       SS
 #define HAL_IO_RADIO_REQN      SS
 #define HAL_IO_RADIO_RDY       3
 #define HAL_IO_RADIO_SCK       SCK
 #define HAL_IO_RADIO_MOSI      MOSI
 #define HAL_IO_RADIO_MISO      MISO
 #define HAL_IO_RADIO_RESET     9
 #define HAL_IO_RADIO_ACTIVE    8

 //#define HAL_IO_LED0          2
 //#define HAL_IO_LED1          6
 */
```

New Result:

• Same output in the console for Line 1 "Adafruit Bluefruit Low Energy nRF8001 Print echo demo".

• Typing "getState()" in console and hitting enter gives a massive parallel string of characters which crashes Arduino IDE

This looks like the BTLE breakout board may actually be working properly, but the data incoming to the Micro isn't being parsed properly.

Comment: It is **not** a hardware question and is appropriate here.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I have the same Arduino micro board and same BLE shield.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Adafruit github page for their [Bluetooth Low Energy Breakout](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_nRF8001) board.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link to the GH page. I hadn't seen it yet. However I'm using an Arduino Micro (pictured in OP) which means the pinouts are different from the UNO.

Comment: I understand the issue is that you are not using an Uno. The link I posted states where the pins are defined (in code).

Comment: That makes more sense. I've definitely got more progress now with output appearing in the console, although now it's hanging in the Arduino IDE! Updating OP ^.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about remapping the pins. Code that uses SPI will access it via the SPI peripheral in the MCU, which already knows the "correct" pins to use. So as long as the software uses the built-in SPI peripheral and the hardware connects to the SPI pins there is no need to change either.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The MCU data sheet looks like it could be capable of this but I can't find any documentation for it specifically. Also the Arduino Micro page says that the separately labelled pins are are specific for the MISO, MOSI, SCK, SS, etc... Can you share a link to documentation for the MCU doing this in the Micro? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the datasheet section labelled "SPI"?

Comment: Yes. It does seem to conclude that changing the pins read from the BlueFruit wouldn't be necessary. Although with the normal pinout as stated in the Adafruit layout for the Uno, this arrangement doesn't work. I've tried it multiple times now with the result in the OP. This is the whole reason I'm asking. Thanks for shedding more light on the data sheet though.

Comment: Updated original post with new results above.